# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48) when I play a sound

Tags: swift, audio

Whenever I try to assign a sound file to a variable my app crashes. I've double checked my sound file names, but I can't get it to work.
Here is my code:

```
struct variables {

    static var randomCode = 0
    static var timerCounter = 30
    static var timer = Timer()
    static var explosion:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    static var defuseSound:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //Error occurs on the following line
    let explosionFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "explosion", ofType: ".mp3") 
    let defuseFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "defused", ofType: ".mp3")

    do {
        try variables.explosion = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: explosionFile!))
        try variables.defuseSound = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: defuseFile!))
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: try "mp3" instead of ".mp3" in ofType param. App is probably crashing because file path is nil and you are forcefully unwrapping it later in do block

Comment: That didn't work either, but thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered many times, the AVAudioPlayer doesnt take arguments anymore when assigning it to a variable or constant.

```
 static var explosion : AVAudioPlayer? 
 static var defuseSound : AVAudioPlayer? 

// OR static var explosion : AVAudioPlayer! = nil
```