# How to play sound in customer class and recognize the end of sound play

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I want play a mp3 file in the swift application in a separate class (not in the viewController class) and recognize the end of sound.
My code send an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in AppDelegate.swift.

Here my code:

**UIViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let soundM = soundManager()
        soundM.loadFile("glass_ping", soundType: "mp3")
        soundM.playNow()
```

**soundManager.swift**

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer();

class soundManager: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    override init()
    {
        super.init();
        print("hallo")
    }

    func playNow(){
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

    func loadFile(_ soundName: String, soundType: String){
        let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundName, ofType: soundType)

        do{
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound!))
            audioPlayer.delegate = self
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.rate = 2.0
            //audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 2
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        print("finish")
    }
```

Any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: I'd verify that `sound` is not `nil`

Comment: This was answered many many times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59237456/thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x48-when-i-play-a-sound/59238540#59238540

Comment: keep your object global

Comment: Thank you all. Sound is not nil. exc_bad_access appears in the row, where I set the delegate.

Comment: No K4747Z you did get the problem. This not the same. The exception runs after set the delegate: audioPlay.delegate=self.

Comment: Hi prashant tukadiya, My object is already outside of any func even outside of my soundManager class. Not seen?

Answer (score 0):

I found a very strange solution an Im not sure why it's works:

**UIViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var player: AudioPlayerComposition!
    @IBOutlet weak var power: Visualizer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Get URL to resouce, create audioPlayer

        let audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer();
        player = AudioPlayer(player: audioPlayer)
        //player.play()
```

**AudioPlayer.swift**

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class AudioPlayer: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    private var player: AVAudioPlayer

    init(player: AVAudioPlayer, view: Visualizer) {
        self.player = player                
        super.init()
        self.loadFile("test", soundType: "mp3")
    }

    func loadFile(_ soundName: String, soundType: String){
        let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundName, ofType: soundType)
        do {
            self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound!))
            self.player.prepareToPlay()
            self.player.play()
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        print ("Finish")
    }
```

This is really working. But as mention no clue why?